# Process Hundreds of Input Files Using AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I have 3 folders containing files as follow:

1. Folder1 contains only 1 file called "data".
2. Folder2 contains more than a hundred files that their names start with "part1" with the same text structure.
3. Folder3 contains more than a hundred files that their names start with "part2" with the same text structure.

I've created a program using AWK that takes as input the file from folder1, **only 1 file** from folder2 and **only 1 file** from folder3, and it works well.

Now i want to give the program all the files from all the folders as input, therefore, **i need a test method** to know that the program has finished from the first 2 files (part1* + part2*) and will start to process the next ones, in order to reset all the variables and arrays for the new processing.

The program will be run like this:

```
$ awkprogram folder1/data folder2/part1* folder3/part2*
```

Comment: What you want to do is trivial but your question is unclear so there's many answers that might be correct. [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input (e.g. the 3 directories you mention with a couple of small files in each of the 2nd and 3rd directories) and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
FNR==1 {                   # for every first record of every file
    filecounter++          # count how manyth file is being processed
}
FNR==1 && filecounter > 2 { # once two first files has been processed
    # reset variables       # do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Actually that's a good idea but it could work only for the 2nd 2 files and not for 3rd, 4th.. Maybe something like: `FNR==1 && FILENAME ~/part/{#reset variables}`

Comment: Of course using the filenames would be the best but your question is a bit unclear on the them: _more than a hundred files that their names start with "part1" [and] "part2"_ vs. _has finished from the first 2 files (part1* + part2*)_.

Comment: FYI GNU awk has `ARGIND` builtin to do what you're doing with `filecounter`.